# Spring Security 302 redirection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with Spring Security, when i access to my registration page and i click on the register button, it redirects me automatically to the login page. In the console Chrome a status code 302 is indicated. 
I tried several things but without success...

here is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/registration").permitAll()

            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()

            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/consultAccount").permitAll()
            .and()// logout
            .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (email.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("email is empty");
        }

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + email + " not found");
        }

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
@Controller
public class BankController {
    @Autowired
    private BankService bankService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/account")
    public String index() {
        return "account";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@Valid User user,
                               BindingResult bindingResult,
                               RedirectAttributes RedirectAttributes) {
        String originalPassword = user.getPassword();

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) return "registration";
        try {
            userService.saveUser(user);
            securityService.autoLogin(user.getEmail(), originalPassword);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            RedirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("exception", e.getMessage());
            return "redirect:/registration";
        }
        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Authentification</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
    <br/><br/>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST" class="form-signin" style="width:30%;margin:auto">
            <h3 class="form-signin-heading" align="center">Pay My Buddy</h3>

            <br/>
             <div align="center" th:if="${param.error}">
                <p style="font-size: 20; color: #FF1C19;">Username or password is invalid</p>
            </div>

            <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  th:placeholder="email"
                class="form-control" /> <br/> 
            <input type="password"  th:placeholder="Password"
                id="password" name="password" class="form-control" /> <br />

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit" th:text="Login"></button>
            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="/registration">Create an account</a></h4>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

registration.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Create an account</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

            <form th:action="@{/register}" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form" style="width:30%;margin:auto">
                <h3 class="form-signin-heading" align="center">Registration Form</h3><br/> 

                        <input type="text" th:value="${user.firstName}" placeholder="Name" name="firstName" class="form-control" />
                        <span th:errors="${user.firstName}" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <br/> 
                        <input type="text" th:value="${user.lastName}" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" class="form-control" /> 
                        <span th:errors="${user.lastName}" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="text" th:value="${user.email}" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control" />
                        <span th:errors="${user.email}" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <br/> 
                        <input type="password" th:value="${user.password}" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                        <span th:errors="${user.password}" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <br/> 
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" th:text="Register"></button>

            </form>

        <div th:if="${exception}" style="width:30%;margin:auto;padding: 1% 0;">
                <p th:text="${exception}" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user registers, you are making a POST request to "/register".

However, "/register" requires a user to be authenticated.

You can add

```
.antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
```

to your security configuration in order to allow unauthenticated users to register.